# GAE: Efficiently querying entities and their referenced entities

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am trying to efficiently return a list of entities, and their respective referenced entities in a template view. For example

We are working with two Kinds:

```
class Event(ndb.Model):
    """An fun activity or event"""
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    venue = ndb.KeyProperty()

class Venue(ndb.Model):
    """The venue of an event"""
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    address = StringProperty()
```

The `Event` kind references `Venue` via an `ndb.KeyProperty()`. To display a list of events and their respective venues into a template, I can first do this query:

```
# we can fetch this from memcache
events = Event.query().fetch()
```

Then, in my view:

```
{% for event in events %}
    Event Name: {{event.name}}
    Event Venue: {{event.venue.get().name}}  # is this line costly?
{% endfor %}
```

With this method, I think that for each event, there will be `get()` call for its respective venue. If this is true, it sounds expensive. Assuming that there are 100 events. Each page load would incur 100 `event.venue.get().name` requests. This means that a modest 10000 page views per day would incur **10000 * 100** .get() requests. Does that sound correct?

Is this the best approach to this problem? If not, what options can I consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, depending on the total number of venues in your dataset, they may all easily fit into Memcache. So unless a venue is modified, you can go for days without touching the datastore - regardless of the number of page views. Make sure you use Memcache for your venues too.

Second, a more efficient way to retrieve entities is in a batch request. Loop through your events, create a list of all venues that you need (by the way, which may be smaller than the number of events if several events happen in the same venue - I don't see that check in your code), then issue a batch request for all venues.

Comment: Can you show, in code, how I might match each venue to each event after retrieving the venues in batch?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Python code to fetch all of the venue names:

```
venue_keys = set(event.venue for event in events)
venues = ndb.get_multi(venue_keys)
venue_name = {venue.key, venue.name for venue in venues}
```

Then, in your template, you can use:

```
Event Venue: {{ venue_name.get(event.venue, 'No venue') }}
```

Comment: Awesome! Now I can retrieve all events and venues from memcache!